# No result found when searching a table

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("t");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
  var n = document.getElementById("noresults");
  if ( on == 0 && n ) {
    n.style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("qt").innerHTML = myInput.value;
  } else {
    n.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Context:
This is the code for searching and displaying data from a table.The searching works well but it doesnot shows "No result found message " when the result is not found.I need the warning message "no result found" only when the searched result not in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a small change to your code at this line

```
tr[i].style.display = "";

  to

tr[i].style.display = "block";
```